# Use comma sign to show precision instead of period sign in Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, decimal

I am using Dataloader to upsert some records but my decimals will not load because the values are not valid. The decimal uses a comma sign to separate the whole from the precision (so for example 2,34 instead of 2.34).
Is there a way to use this notation and not the standard notation?
Thanks

Comment: Check if the locale of the user (you?) is set correctly (e.g. French, Dutch) ? This may solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the locale is set correctly